# how to get latitude and longitude for placeMarker in my map along with my address when im moving my marker to a specified place that i located

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script>
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

var _map;
var _originMarker, _destinationMarker;
var _geocoder;

function initialize()
{
   var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.1289956,82.7791754)
    };
    _map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    _geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    _originMarker=createMarker('search-from');
    _destinationMarker=createMarker('search-to');


    google.maps.event.addListener(_map, 'click', function(mouseEvent)
    {
        if ((_activeMarker != null) && (!_activeMarker.getMap())) placeMarker(_activeMarker, mouseEvent.latLng);
    });
}





function createMarker(_autoComplId)
{
    var _autoCompl = document.getElementById(_autoComplId);
    var _newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        draggable: true,
        map: null,
        autoCompl: _autoCompl
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(_newmarker, "dragend", function(event)
    {
        placeMarker(_newmarker, _newmarker.getPosition());
    });

    var _autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(_autoCompl);
    _autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
    google.maps.event.addListener(_autocomplete, 'place_changed', function()
    {
        var _place = _autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (_place.geometry == null) return;
        setCenterAndZoom(_place.geometry.location, 16);
        placeMarker(_newmarker, _place.geometry.location);
    });

    return _newmarker;  
}

function placeMarker(_marker, _location)
{
    _marker.setPosition(_location);
    RenewAddress(_marker);
}

function RenewAddress(_marker)
{
    _geocoder.geocode({'latLng': _marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            if (_marker.getMap() == null) _marker.setMap(_map);
            _marker.autoCompl.value = results[0].formatted_address;
        }
    });
}


function setCenterAndZoom(_center, _zoom)
{
    _map.setCenter(_center);
    _map.setZoom(_zoom);
}

var _activeMarker = null;
function setActiveMarker(index)
{
    switch(index)
    {
        case 0:
            _activeMarker = _originMarker;
            break;
        case 1:
            _activeMarker = _destinationMarker;
    }
}

</script>
```

- this is what im using to retrieve address,
- and now i want to retrieve latitude and longitude along with my
  address, in the above function RenewAddress(_marker)

iam using the `_geocoder.geocode({'latLng': _marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status)`

- but iam unable to retrieve it i just got the result of the address
  auto filled in the text box as an output but iam unable to retrieve
  latitude and longitude

Comment: What does this syntax do, that you've got wrapped around your two functions? `![ ... ]` ?

Comment: sry it was quoted by me by mistake i removed them

Comment: How are you "retrieving the address"?  The coordinates should be _marker.getPosition(), how are you using that to retrieve the coordinates, and what makes you believe that isn't working?

Comment: this was my script iam using to retrieve address but iam unable to retrieve latitude and longitude

Comment: As geocodezip said: use just, for example `var latlng = _marker.getPosition();` in function `RenewAddress()`. `latlng.lat()` and `latlng.lng()` will retrieve marker latitude and longitude.

Comment: @Anto Jurković thankyou your idea was good but im not able to retriew the latitude and longitude anyways

Comment: What do you mean with 'not able to retrieve'? That values are wrong/undefined or you want to use them on some other place in the code? I'm asking that because I get proper values in console.log for lat, lng and address in function `RenewAddress()`

Comment: @Anto Jurković   i used it like this ,,is this the correct way to use ? , or please tell me how to put it properly in the code ,
   function RenewAddress(_marker)
{
    _geocoder.geocode({'latLng': _marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            if (_marker.getMap() == null) _marker.setMap(_map);
            _marker.autoCompl.value = results[0].formatted_address;
        }
    });
var latlng = _marker.getPosition();
latlng.lat();
latlng.lng();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My version of `RenewAddress()` function is almost the same as your except that I retrieve lat/lng values before and show them in console.

```
function RenewAddress(_marker) {
    console.log('RenewAddress');

    var latlng = _marker.getPosition();
    console.log(latlng.lat());
    console.log(latlng.lng());

    _geocoder.geocode({'latLng': _marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log('status ok');
            if (_marker.getMap() == null) 
                _marker.setMap(_map);
            _marker.autoCompl.value = results[0].formatted_address;
            console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
            console.log(_marker.autoCompl.value);

            var exactAddress = document.getElementById('search-to');
            exactAddress.value = _marker.autoCompl.value + ', lat/lng: ' + latlng.lat() + ':' + latlng.lng();
        } else {
            console.log('error: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/futol/1/edit) with only one marker and latitude and longitude fields. Write something to `town/city/country` field, for example Odisha. Select it. After that marker should be shown, exact address should be set and latitude and longitude fields. If you move marker around, information will be changed.

Comment: Now, question is what do you want to do with those lat/lng values? Just writing them into console is not very useful except for debugging.

Comment: So using marker `getPosition()` you can always get its lat/lng values in the same way.

Comment: check the above link you will get an idea what iam asking for

Comment: Which field do you want to update with address and lat/lng? The last one: `contact address`?

Comment: Updated. You will have to format it as you like.  I'm not sure why you create two markers. Moving any of them will change address and lat/lng info.

Comment: Did you scroll the field to the end? At the end of the field, there is  latitude and longitude written. After the address. It would be better to have separated fields for latitude and longitude, like for email, address... and update those fields.

Comment: Updated with example at jsbin.

Comment: Updated link is at the end of answer :-). 'See example at jsbin with...'

Comment: can i get only country and city /town address how can i restrict the other street address in auto fill form ?